# Why are my olives discolouring in their brine?

Tags: brining

Olives are in 10% saline solution for 4 weeks. They are black kalamatas. Notice they are losing the black colour and are now splochy. Why is this occurring?

Thanks

Comment: were your olives originally colored or naturally black?

Comment: The kalamatta olives were naturally black. That, is they were picked ripe.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to answer, but while searching for the name of the product used to make the olives black I found this perfect answer from http://www.oliveoilsource.com/asktheexpert/are-olives-dyed-make-them-black

> Olives naturally turn black as they ripen. When unripe they are green.
> As they ripen they get reddish, then purplish and finally black.
>
> "Ripe Black Olives" in a can are actually olives which are neither
> black nor ripe when they are picked.  They are picked very green and
> then cured using dilute brine and lye solutions.
>
> Lye treatments cause natural phenolic compounds in the olives to oxidize to a black color.
> Calcium chloride salts, iron salts (ferrous gluconate) and compressed
> air bubbled through the curing vats help develop the black color. So
> there is no black dye used but the olives are treated to make them a
> nice uniform dark black.
>
> **Home curing of olives without these added salts will result in mottled
> and brownish olives which taste just as good** but are not as
> attractive.
>
> The opposite tact is used to make a nice green California- style
> green-ripe olive. Air containing oxygen must be excluded to avoid
> natural oxidation and darkening of the skins.